# The payment for the registration fee has failed.

Tags: android, google-play

I have registered my company gmail account with developer console for publishing android apps 6 months ago and i have published apps successfully. Now i am try to publish another app with the same account, its asking for registration:

> In order to access your account, you need a successful registration fee payment

I have search google [offcial blog](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113468?hl=en) and its says google requires only one time registration. whats the issue i am not getting it.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right Google account?

Comment: yeah i am 100% sure. My apps are on playstore with this account.

Comment: I'd contact Google about it

Comment: how did you contact. Did you create any issue? How they respond?

Answer (score 0):

Clear All Browser cache and cookies or use another browser. It happens if another google account tried to login before.